# Trigger smart speaker announcement via HTTP request

Tags: automation, http-post, google-home, google-assistant

I have a smart speaker with buit-in Google Assistant which I want to automatically make announcements at specific times. The times are determined by a program I wrote running in the cloud which can send HTTP POST requests at those times (e.g. to trigger a Telegram bot or anything else with a usable API).

Is there a way to send POST requests directly to my smart speaker with a message to announce? Or would I need some intermediary app/service to integrate with Google Assistant?

Comment: I am looking for the same answer. I want to tell the speaker saying "bed time, kids" at 20:30 for example. @J-J, have you figured this out?

Comment: I have not. However, your requirement seems simple: if it's a regular bed time then just set up a routine on your phone which broadcasts to your specified home device(s). My difficulty is the times of my broadcasts are determined in code each day.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the [Google Assistant SDK](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/overview) to send POST requests directly to your smart speaker with a message to announce. The Google Assistant SDK lets you add voice control, natural language understanding and Google’s smarts to your ideas. Your project captures an utterance (a spoken audio request, such as What's on my calendar?), sends it to the Google Assistant, and receives a spoken audio response in addition to the raw text of the utterance.

You can also refer to the [Google Broadcast](https://support.google.com/googlenest/answer/7531913?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid#zippy=%2Cwhat-you-need) and [Routines](https://support.google.com/assistant/answer/7672035?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid) feature using which you can make announcements at specific times .